# Semantic Ui classes ui form breaks Angular2 validation

Tags: angular, semantic-ui, angular2-forms

I have made a demo on plunker so the problem is that when adding class="ui form" to form element angular2 validation breaks.

PLUNKER WITHOUT (class="ui form"): [linkPlunker1](http://plnkr.co/edit/CnfKJjHUniWVRVZDVVmF?p=preview)

```
<form [ngFormModel]="myForm">
```

PLUNKER WITH (class="ui form"): [linkPlunker2](http://plnkr.co/edit/20v4t2XZ1Xd5hKiuFa0b?p=preview)

```
<form [ngFormModel]="myForm" class="ui form">
```

Comment: They seem to behave the same here. What browser are you using? I tried with Chrome.

Comment: I tried with chrome

Comment: Both Plunkers are the same. If I add the classes I can reproduce.

Comment: You need to use `error` class on form http://plnkr.co/edit/GsM5tKFooEPqkpiP8j1p?p=preview Semantic-ui.css `.ui.form.error .error.message:not(:empty) {   display: block }`

Comment: @yurzui You should put it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an issue with semantic.css which applies

```
.ui.form .error.message, .ui.form {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: i also added .ng-invalid {
    background-color: #fff6f6 !important;
    border-color: #e0b4b4 !important;
} for the input element to my stylesheet. Do you have a better solution

Comment: Sorry, I don't know SemanticUI. I just debugged it to see that it's caused by CSS, not by Angular.

Comment: I have found better solution if anybody needs it. .ui.input.error input {
    background-color: #fff6f6 !important;
    border-color: #e0b4b4 !important;
}